# How to write integration tests depending on Druid?

Tags: scala, testing, scalatest, druid

I am coding an application that generates reports from a Druid database. My integration tests need to read data from that database.

My current approach involves creating synthetic data for each of the tests. However, I am unable to remove data created from the database (be it by removing entries or completely dropping the schema). Tried [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/druid-user/V4pbcZC7rjU) but still getting data back after disabling the segment and firing the kill task.

I think that either I am completely wrong with my approach or there is a way to delete information from the database that I haven't been able to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I worked around the issue by inserting data in Druid with ids specific to each unit test and querying for that.

Not very elegant since now one malicious test can (potentially) mess with the results of another test.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by below 2 approaches

**Approach 1 :**

- Disable the segment(used=0)
- Fire a kill task for that segment
- Have the load and drop rules

Refer : http://druid.io/docs/latest/ingestion/tasks.html (look for destroying segments)

**Approach 2 :** (prefer this for doing integration tests before setting up production):

- stop coordinator node and delete all entires in the druid_segments
     table in the metadata store
- stop historical node and delete everything inside the directory pointed by `druid.segmentCache.locations` at historical node
- start coordinator and historical nodes

Remember this will delete everything from druid cluster.